# Edit link link for favorite tags plays peekaboo

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

ARGH MAKE IT STOP! *cough* But yes, for some reason the edit link next to Favorite Tags disappears whenever I click anywhere on the page on sites where I have no favorite tags.

[image: culprit link]

There's probably a good chance it's just not supposed to be displayed in this case at all, but the current behaviour of it performing a disappearing act whenever I do anything is extremely obnoxious. For the sake of my sanity, please either hide it immediately or prevent it from hiding altogether.

Comment: Reproduced: it disappears but does do its job of creating the box to enter a new favourite tag (it doesn't come back if you click off however)

Comment: That's a brand new bughavior, I always click in Meta front page, no favorite tags and it never disappeared like this. Wow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's been doing it [since Friday](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1784326#1784326), but I'm not sure if it was before that.

Comment: Repro on IE11/Chrome/FF and Safari on win7

Comment: Reproduced by the Powers that Me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

The UI here went through some refinement recently, and this was missed.